# Hibernate Criteria for assotiated objects

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria, hibernate-criteria

I have the next structure of DTO objects:

```
public class MainDTO implements Serializable {
    private Long mainId;
    private String name;
    ... //some other fields
    private boolean disabled;

    @ManyToOne()
    @JoinColumn(name = "root_id")
    private RootDTO root;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "child_id", updatable = false, referencedColumnName = "child_id")
    @Cascade(value = { CascadeType.ALL, CascadeType.DELETE_ORPHAN })
    private ChildDTO child;

    ...
}

public class RootDTO implements Serializable {
    ... //some other fields
    private boolean disabled;

    ...
}


public class ChildDTO implements Serializable {
    private Long childId;
    ... //some other fields
    private boolean disabled;

    @ManyToOne()
    @JoinColumn(name = "info_id")
    private InfoDTO info;

    ...
}

public class InfoDTO implements Serializable {
    private Long infoId;
    ... //some other fields
    private boolean disabled;

    ...
}
```

I need to fill `Map<String, Map<Long, Long>>` (`<name from MainDTO, <mainId from MainDTO, infoId from InfoDTO >>`) with next restrictions:

MainDTO.disabled = false,

MainDTO.root != null,

MainDTO.root.disabled = false,

MainDTO.child.disabled = false,

MainDTO.child.info != null,

MainDTO.child.info.disabled = false

Here is the code I've written, but got stuck in select infoId from InfoDTO:

```
Criteria rootCriteria = getSession().createCriteria(
        MainDTO.class);

// check that root is enabled
rootCriteria.createCriteria("root", "root").add(
    Restrictions.eq("disabled", false));

// check that child is enabled
Criteria childCriteria = rootCriteria
    .createCriteria("child", "child")
    .add(Restrictions.eq("disabled", false))
    .add(Restrictions.isNotNull("info"));

// check that info is enabled
childCriteria
    .createCriteria("info", "info")
    .add(Restrictions.eq("disabled", false));

ProjectionList rootProjection = Projections.projectionList()
    .add(Projections.property("mainId"))
    .add(Projections.property("name"))
    .add(Projections.property("child.info")); //HOW TO SELECT ONLY ID??
rootCriteria.setProjection(rootProjection);
rootCriteria.add(Restrictions.eq("disabled", false))
    .add(Restrictions.isNotNull("root"))
    .add(Restrictions.isNotNull("child"));
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, calling entities DTO is really confusing.

Now regarding your question, you should use the aliases you defined in your projections

```
ProjectionList rootProjection = 
    Projections.projectionList()
               .add(Projections.property("mainId"))
               .add(Projections.property("name"))
               .add(Projections.property("info.infoId"));
```

Also, given that you're doing an inner join to root and child, the last two restrictions are not necessary: the inner joins already make sure those are not null.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Maybe you can help me with another issue: this rootCriteria.list() returns the next structure: Object[Object[3]] when I expected just Object[3] to convert it to my Map. Maybe I should add some group statement?

Comment: The criteria.list() method returns a list. Each element of the list is a row returned by your query, represented as an array of Objects. And each row has three columns. The criteria.list() method should thus return a List<Object[]>, each Object[] having 3 elements.

Comment: now it returns List<Object[]>, where Object[] contains it's own Object[3]. (in my test) List<Object[]> result = rootCriteria.list(); returned List<Object[39224]> with size 31232 and each of the List's Object[39224] contains Object[3]. It means that I got 39224*31232 Object[3]

Comment: I've never seen that happen. Don't you do anything alse than the code you listed with the root criteria? No ResultTransformer or something like that?

Comment: nope. only what i've chaged is child.info -> info.infoId and removed 2 last isNotNull restrictions. UPD: when i run generated query on DB it returned for me only 3 columns as expected

Comment: forget it... i was confused in debugger. thanks again for your help.